# How do I get Robospice to treat anything other than a 200 response from Retrofit & OKHttp as an error

Tags: android, httprequest, robospice, retrofit, okhttp

I am using Robospice on android with Retrofit and OKHttp. All works great with responses passed back to the activity using the Robospice RequestListener. The problem is that it only returns a failure if the connection times out or another network issue. If a 401 is returned then it is classed as a success but with a null response as it couldn't parse the JSON into our MobileAppSetup POJO.

At the moment I'm having to do null checking on the response but I have no idea what the reason was if it was a server error or a valid 401.

```
public final class HTTPRequestListener implements RequestListener<MobileAppSetup> {

    @Override
    public void onRequestFailure(SpiceException spiceException) {
        Log.d("", "failure:"+ spiceException);
        loginProgress.hide();

    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestSuccess(final MobileAppSetup response) {
        Log.d("","success. Data: "+response);

        if(response==null)
            showDialog("Error logging in", "Please check your username and password and try again.", "");

        loginProgress.hide();

        postLoginProcess(response);

    }
}
```

I need to pass these errors to the onRequestFailure callback so I can properly handle it. Is there a way to specify error codes that Robospice should treat as an error. I think it involves adding some kind of custom error handler but really can't find a solution at the moment.

Comment: That is really something to look for on the Retrofit forum, it's only loosely related to RS.

Comment: @Snicolas this due to  okhttp client bug, it's better to try with new latest release.

Answer (score 2):

This due to the bug in OKHTTP client **[possible bug](https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/281)**!

> Problem is When the server answers with a 401 Unauthorized responses,
>   the Callback object calls its failure() method..
>
> When the server returns with the 401 status, the `RetrofitError`
>   response object is null, and the `networkError` flag is set to true,
>   making it impossible for the app to check
>   `error.getResponse().getStatus()` I believe the error lies on the http
>   client. When using *OkClient* I get this error: java.io.IOException:
>   No authentication challenges found

I suggest you to download new okhttp jar file from [square/okhttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp/)  run the project again! or try with any other client instead of okhttp.